# Determine all values function reaches local max

Tags: maxima-minima

Determine all $x > 0$ where function $f(x) = 1 + \int_{-x}^{x}\cos(t^2) dt $ reaches local maximum. I took the derivative of this function and got $f^\prime(x) = 2\cos(x^2)$ but further i put this equal to zero but can't find out the values for which $\cos(x^2) = 0$. It would be a great help if someone tells me how to find the value where function($\cos(x^2) = 0)$?

Comment: You have $\cos(u) = 0$ when $u$ is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Hint: have you tried looking at the unit circle? Particularly at the points where that lie on the vertical axis?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes i did but the table/graph has not all values , i mean i can see that cos(x) is zero at $\pi/2$ but it is $\cos(x^2)$. I was looking for an easy method if there is any. :-)

Comment: $$\theta=x^2\\\cos(\theta)=0\\\theta\in\left\{\dots,-\frac{3\pi}2,-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2,\frac{3\pi}2,\dots\right\}\\x=\sqrt\theta$$